# Can Java use user defined object as an index of 2D array key?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

```
array[obj][obj] = 1;
```

I want to create 2D array whose index is user defined object. How to do this? or there is some other data structure available to do this?

Comment: And if you must use an array, call 'Array.newInstance()'

Comment: as commented by chrylis, use Map<keyObj, ValueObj>. Although, keep in mind that you may need to implement the `hashCode` and `equals` for the keyObj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) states that an array can only be accessed using an `int`. Though thanks to primitive type promotion, `short`, `char` and `byte` can be used as well as they get automatically converted to `int`.

To solve your problem: You can store an `int` index inside your object and then use that to access the array.

```
array[obj.getIndex()][obj.getIndex()] = 1;
```

If you cannot directly influence the code of the user defined object, force the user to implement an `interface` that requires the `getIndex()` method.

```
interface ArrayIndexable {

    int getIndex();

}
```

Alternatively if you cannot force the user to implement the interface, then you can maintain some sort of index using a map that maps the object to an `int`.

```
int x = ...;
int y = ...;
int[][] array = new int[x][y];

Map<SomeClass, Integer> index = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < Math.max(x, y); i++) {
    SomeClass m = ...; // object associated with i
    index.put(m, i);
}

SomeClass obj = ...;

// accessing the array
array[index.get(obj)][index.get(obj)] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In an array, the index can be only one of the following short, byte, char or int.
For your use case, you might want to use a HashMap, it is a collection of keys and corresponding values. Key can be any user defined object and value can also be any defined object.
A simple hashmap example where keys are of type String and values are of type Double.

```
  HashMap hm = new HashMap();
  // Put elements to the map
  hm.put("Zara", new Double(3434.34));
  hm.put("Mahnaz", new Double(123.22));
  hm.put("Ayan", new Double(1378.00));
  hm.put("Daisy", new Double(99.22));
  hm.put("Qadir", new Double(-19.08));
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it array indices can be only integer in java but there is a way to achieve this.

Associate array indices to object using hashmap, and for each value retrive the index value using object as a key and use it as index.

//This example will help you

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Experiment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a[]=new int[10];
        HashMap<Student,Integer>map=new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            map.put(new Student(),i);
            a[i]=i;
        }

        ArrayList al=new ArrayList(map.keySet());
        int x;

        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            x=map.get(al.get(i));
            System.out.print(a[x] + " " + " ");
        }
    }
}

class Student{
    int a,b;
}
```

But do remember hashmap doesn't preserve the insertion order.

Please comment if you face any problem or accept if works.

You can go for treemap if you want insertion order.